# Как заставить телеграмм бота отправлять сообщения раз в 15 минут в определенный канал на js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegraf

Сейчас ознакомился с библиотекой telegraf, создал бота, который пишет нужный мне текст, когда присылаешь ему сообщение:

```
const Telegraf = require('telegraf')

const telegramToken = 'мой токен'

const text = 'мой текст'

const bot = new Telegraf.Telegraf(telegramToken)

bot.on('message', async (ctx) => {
    ctx.reply(text)
})

bot.launch().then()
```

Теперь мне нужно добавить такой функционал, как авто рассылка, то есть, чтобы он условно каждые 15 минут писал в определенную беседу или
чат, как это можно реализовать? Не получается найти в интернете.

Answer (score 0):

```
const Telegraf = require('telegraf')

const telegramToken = '...'
const text = 'мой текст'

const bot = new Telegraf.Telegraf(telegramToken)

repeatMessage = async function(message) {
    setInterval(() => {
        let chatId = 1; //id чата 
        bot.telegram.sendMessage(chatId, text);
    }, 15*60*1000)
}
repeatMessage()

bot.on('message', async(ctx) => {
    console.log(ctx.message.chat.id)
    ctx.reply(text)
})

bot.launch().then()
```